# Styles not injected via props in material-ui typescript component in react native

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, react-native, material-ui

```
import {createStyles, WithStyles} from "@material-ui/core";

const styles = (theme: Theme) => createStyles({
    root: {}
});

interface MyProps extends WithStyles<typeof styles> {
}

export class MyComponent extends Component<MyProps> {

    constructor(props: MyProps) { 
        super(props);
        console.log(props.classes); // why this is undefined? 
    }
}
```

Why props.classes is undefined?

Comment: Seems you didn't send props 'classes' to MyComponent

Comment: @NooruddinLakhani so how do i send them?

Comment: Thanks @NooruddinLakhani but I want to use the styles const within the component class

Comment: checkout this way https://malcoded.com/posts/react-component-style/

Answer (score 0):

You can send props to component like where you calling

```
<MyComponent classes={.. Any thing you want to pass here ...} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it working by "decorating" my class like this

```
export const MyComponent = withStyles(styles)(
    class extends Component<MyProps> {
      ...
    }
)
```

Then you can use the styles like this

```
<div className={this.props.classes.root}>
```